# I know that presently order by is not there in BeamSQL is there any work around for it

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

This is present

```java
PCollection<BeamRecord> rec = rec_out.apply(BeamSql.query(
  "SELECT bnk_name,state_name,val from PCOLLECTION order by val desc limit 2"));
```

But I need

```java
PCollection<BeamRecord> rec = rec_out.apply(BeamSql.query(
  "SELECT bnk_name,state_name,val from PCOLLECTION order by val desc "));
```

Comment: What will you do with the data after it is output? What is the purpose of the order?

Answer (score 0):

This actually wouldn't help. PCollections are unordered in Beam, so you cannot apply ordering to the whole output.

Beam does not have ordering because it is usually not necessary, often not possible. Most problems where ordering is used have another solution that does not require global sorting.

If you describe more about what you will do with the output of the SQL query, I will update my answer with advice.

If you cannot share more, then you have the option of using Beam's [sorter extension](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/java-extensions/#sorter) outside of the SQL query, but again it is not really for global sorting, but per-key order after a shuffle.

Comment: I will store my output Pcollection to a csv file or any database .

Comment: That makes sense - if your data is small enough to store in a database then it is a great choice.